# Powershell script for replying to email

Tags: powershell, outlook, office-automation, com-automation

I am trying to reply to emails using PowerShell, and the code below works successfully, but it doesn't show the original message I'm responding to:

```
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
Add-type -assembly "System.Runtime.Interopservices"

try {
$outlook = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
$outlookWasAlreadyRunning = $true
}
catch {
    try {
    $Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application
    $outlookWasAlreadyRunning = $false
    }
    catch {
        write-host "You must exit Outlook first."
        exit
    }
}

$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)

$Folder = $inbox.Folders | where-object { $_.name -eq "Folder name" }

$mails = $Folder.Items | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "This is the subject"}

foreach($mail in $mails) {
    $reply = $mail.ReplyAll()
    $reply.body = "TEST BODY"
    $reply.save()
    
    $inspector = $reply.GetInspector
    $inspector.display()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your reply is not showing is because you're creating your reply with `$reply = $mail.ReplyAll()` and then replacing the body of that email in this line `$reply.body = "TEST BODY"`

If you wish to retain the existing email, I'd use the [Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2) method on the body string like so:

```
foreach($mail in $mails) {
    $reply = $mail.ReplyAll()
    $text = "TEST BODY`r`n"

    # Insert our desired text at position 0 of the existing string content
    $reply.body = $reply.body.Insert(0, $text)
    $reply.save()
    
    $inspector = $reply.GetInspector
    $inspector.display()
}
```

If you're working with HTML-based emails, you'll probably want to update the `HTMLBody` field instead, so replace

```
$reply.body = $reply.body.Insert(0, $text)
```

with this

```
$reply.HTMLBody = $reply.HTMLBody.Insert(0, $text)
```

Comment: For HTMLBody, the new text must be inserted after the `body` tag, not in the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no need to iterate over all items in the folder checking the subject property:

```
$mails = $Folder.Items | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "This is the subject"}
```

Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to get only items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

As for the message body, in the code it is replaced with a plain text:

```
$reply.body = "TEST BODY"
```

To preserve the original message body you need to add your content right after the opening `<body>` tag and use the `HTMLBody` property instead. The `Body` property contains a plain text.

Also there is no need to get an inspector if you need to display the item after. Use the `Display` method of the `MailItem` class directly.